# How to get the latitude longitude from a google map?

Tags: maps, latitude-longitude

I am programmatically trying to get latitude and logitude for an address on a google map web page. Is there any way to do this?

### Update:

I found out how to do this in the end. Send a request to:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do this in the end. Send a request to:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false